# Create textField allowing both written user input or user click on prefilled options in iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, drop-down-menu, combobox, textfield

I am struggling to find relevant information on customised Text Field with iOS Swift.

I would like to create a TextField where some options have been prefilled for the user to select from IF they would like to, or the user can simply write its own text.

It is very similar to the search in google maps, either you can write fully your origin/destination, either you can click on the "my location" or click on the previous searches. How to create this kind of control ?

My research so far concluded that "combobox" was for macOS and not IOS and pickerview shows a list to be scrolled so does not relevant here.

Does anybody know about an existing solution to this ?

Comment: I think I have found how to do it, you have to create a pop up tableview, it is a not a standard textField.

Answer (score 1):

Will you be able to give a try to https://github.com/apasccon/SearchTextField?

[image: SearchTextField]